# Google colab is showing busy

Tags: jupyter-notebook, gpu, google-colaboratory

I ran a training process on google colab yesterday. Now the google colab is showing busy, even after restarting runtime and interrupting execution. I want to stop the current execution. Please help!

Answer (score 23):

Selecting 'restart runtime' from the runtime menu should suffice.

If for some reason that doesn't work, you can drop your current backend and start fresh with a new one by selecting the command 'Reset all runtimes...' from the Runtime menu.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't it stop the current execution?

Answer (score 20):

It means that your code is running. You don't need to get panicked. Just wait for your code to complete the execution. Your kernel will become ready to use again after that.

As per your scenario, if it's still busy even after complete execution, you can do as in the above answer (Reset session)

Comment: My code is showing "Busy", after an unusually long time. I got a lot of this warning in the cell `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/catalogue.py:138: DeprecationWarning: SelectableGroups dict interface is deprecated. Use select.` . In the bottom tab, it shows Completed, but still seems to be running (cell icon is rotating)! Don't know what to do :|

Answer (score 15):

Same problem: stuck with 'busy' and 'reconnecting' status.

'restart runtime' didn't work.

Change GPU/CPU didn't work.

Runtime -> Manage Sessions -> Terminate worked.

Answer (score 0):

When it happens with me I go to google webpage, disconnect my accounts and log in again. Then the colab comes back to work.

Answer (score 0):

After performing: Runtime -> Manage Sessions -> Terminate worked.
I pressed reconnect on the top right and it was worked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is an update to colab menu options (as I had gone through the previous answers)

From menu:
Runtime -> Disconnect and delete runtime

This should work

Answer (score -9):

I experienced the same issue.

For me, I reset all runtimes, force quit chrome using the task manager and restarted my computer. Some of these steps probably weren't necessary, but the combination of all of them solved the issue for me.

Comment: This is about the google colab online service, this has nothing to do with your computer.