# Colab / Google Cloud SDK - local-runtime always "busy" - cannot restart

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

I am running Colab on Google cloud VM and connecting to it as a local runtime. I interrupted a run and since then the runtime continues to show as busy. I have already terminated all sessions, restarted runtime multiple times, and restarted my local machine and the VM as well, but it continues to show runtime as "busy."
Is there any way to terminate this runtime so I can use my Google cloud VM again?
Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Selecting 'restart runtime' from the runtime menu should be enough. If for some reason that doesn't work, you can drop your current backend and start fresh with a new one by selecting the command 'Reset all runtimes...' from the Runtime menu. We can do the same for those stuck with 'busy' and 'reconnecting' status. You can terminate the colab by :

- Make sure the notebook is connected to an active runtime.
- Click on    **"Runtime"** in the menu bar
- Clink on **"Manage sessions"** in the menu    that appears.
- The window that pops up lists your active sessions.

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833633/google-colab-is-showing-busy) to know how to handle a similar scenario.